# Set Interface Design

Tags: java, arrays, set

Hi I have been having difficulty in creating a set interface that allows me to add integers to a set using an array? My biggest problem is that calling the method I don't know how to iterate through the array so that the next integer is added to the array after the previous and so forth.

```
public class SetInt 
{
    static final int LOWERRANGE = 1;
    static final int UPPERRANGE = 49;
    static final int NOTAMEMBER = 0;

    //class constants used to represent the range of values this set can hold
    //and a dummy value of 0 to represent nothing in the set 

    int[] anArray = new int[50];




public void add(int a) 
{
    anArray[1] = LOWERRANGE;
    anArray[a] = a;
}

/*   prints the set of numbers currently in the set
*/
public void printNumbers()
{

    for(int num = 2 ; num <=47; num++)
    {
        if(anArray[num] != 0)
        {
         System.out.print(" " + anArray[num]);
        }
    }

}

    /* return the minimum value in the set
 * @return the minimum value
 */

public int min()
{
    int minValue = anArray[0];
    for(int i=1; i<anArray.length; i++)
    {  

         if(anArray[i] < minValue)
         {  
             minValue = anArray[i];  
         }  
    }  
    return minValue;  

}
```

Comment: Sry, I don't get your point. What do you want to do? Why you declare these static fields? Why your for loop starts at 2 and end at 47? Why `anArray[1] = LOWERRANGE;`? Please explain more precisely what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry, for this example I must use an array only, meaning the size of it is fixed. The array must hold values between 1 to 49 with position 0 in the array left blank.

Comment: This is an example of the test code                                                  public class TestSetInt
{
 public TestSetInt()
 {
  SetInt test1 = new SetInt();
  
  for(int i = 2; i<49;i=i+3)
   test1.add(i);